# Get rid of padding in table

Tags: html, css

I have a table and I want its header to take all 5 columns. It does, but there is a little padding between header and table borders from which I can't get rid off. I need header to take the whole width of the table. Any suggestions?

```css
.foo {
    min-width: 250px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #515151;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
}

.thClass {
    margin-left: -3px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    margin-top: -2px;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 19px;
    cursor: move;
}

.header{
    margin-left: 17px;
}

.tableBody {
    display: block;
    min-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    cursor: default;
}

.foo tbody tr td {
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#displaySizes {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.disp tbody tr th {
    column-span: all;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.disp tbody tr td {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table class="foo disp elementTable">
                <tr class="tableHeader">
                    <th class="thClass" colspan="5">
                        <span class="header">Device</span>
                        <span class="settings">
                            <img src="Icons/pignon.png" width="17px" height="17px" alt="Settings" title="Settings" />
                        </span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="4" id="sizeContainer">
                        <ul id="displaySizes">
                            <li>4:3</li>
                            <li>16:9</li>
                            <li>Clock</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>$100</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

One way to do this is to set header `display:block;` and then make its `width:102%;`, but in this case `colspan="5"` does not work. Here is a fiddle for you to play with code: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/b996809u/

Comment: Is this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/L5kq479f/

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 No, it only removes the border of header. Little space between header and table's border still remains. I need header to take whole width.

Comment: You can also make use of border-collapse:collapse on .foo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `border-spacing` property. in the snipet below I have used 0px. Browsers use 2px by default

```css
.foo {
    min-width: 250px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #515151;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

.thClass {
    margin-left: -3px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    margin-top: -2px;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 19px;
    cursor: move;
    padding:0;
}

.header{
    margin-left: 17px;
}

.tableBody {
    display: block;
    min-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    cursor: default;
}

.foo tbody tr td {
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#displaySizes {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.disp tbody tr th {
    column-span: all;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.disp tbody tr td {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table class="foo disp elementTable">
                <tr class="tableHeader">
                    <th class="thClass" colspan="5">
                        <span class="header">Device</span>
                        <span class="settings">
                            <img src="Icons/pignon.png" width="17px" height="17px" alt="Settings" title="Settings" />
                        </span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="4" id="sizeContainer">
                        <ul id="displaySizes">
                            <li>4:3</li>
                            <li>16:9</li>
                            <li>Clock</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>$100</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Comment: Np. Good luck with your project.

Comment: You can also use `unset` instead of a value in `px`

Answer (score 1):

You can set `border-collapse: collapse;` for the table itself.

```css
.foo {
    min-width: 250px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #515151;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.thClass {
    margin-left: -3px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    margin-top: -2px;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 19px;
    cursor: move;
}

.header{
    margin-left: 17px;
}

.tableBody {
    display: block;
    min-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    cursor: default;
}

.foo tbody tr td {
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#displaySizes {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.disp tbody tr th {
    column-span: all;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.disp tbody tr td {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table class="foo disp elementTable">
                <tr class="tableHeader">
                    <th class="thClass" colspan="5">
                        <span class="header">Device</span>
                        <span class="settings">
                            <img src="Icons/pignon.png" width="17px" height="17px" alt="Settings" title="Settings" />
                        </span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="4" id="sizeContainer">
                        <ul id="displaySizes">
                            <li>4:3</li>
                            <li>16:9</li>
                            <li>Clock</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>$100</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```